# phpunit assert json_encode array

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent, phpunit

I'm trying to assert that a model I store in mysql is equal to the expected model.
size and color field are both type json.

For this:

```
$productRequest = new ProductRequest();
$productRequest->size = "1,2";
$productRequest->color = ["blue","green"];
$this->productRepository->store($productRequest);

$product = Product::find(1);
$productExpected = new Product();
$productExpected->size = json_encode(explode(",", "1,2"));
$productExpected->color = json_encode(array("blue","green"));
$this->assertEquals($productExpected->getAttributes(), $product->getAttributes());
```

Store method use json_encode and explode the same way.
However assert always failed with this result:

```
-    'size' => '["1","2"]'
-    'color' => '["blue","green"]'
+    'size' => '["1", "2"]'
+    'color' => '["blue", "green"]'
```

I suppose I'm missing something with mysql serialization but can't figure out what is wrong here.

Comment: First, this is what `assertDatabaseHas` is for. Second, the spaces in your JSON suggest that you are doing something wrong in your controller code when you store the data. JSON created by PHP `json_encode` will not have spaces after commas.

Comment: I'm not satisfy with `assertDatabaseHas` because if I add attributes to store function my test will still assert true. store function receive the request then `$product->color = json_encode($request->color);$product->size = json_encode(explode(",", $request->size));`

Comment: Why is the model's `$casts` property not handling JSON encoding?

Comment: First, thx I change the way I handle array to json by using $casts.
Second : the problem seems to appear with `$model->getAttributes()`, I solved the problem by using `$model->toArray` in assert. However I didn't find any relevant information about why `getAttributes()' return different values in my case.